# "Sign Up/Join Now" versus "Learn More/Find Out More"

Tags: registration, signup-signon, conversion, cta

Does anyone have any insight regarding the use of a Sign Up "Call to Action" (CTA) versus a Learn More CTA? Here's my thinking:

"Sign Up" is ideal in situations where the lead is MOST informed about, or has the MOST confidence in a product. (As much as possible, anyway.) Either the product is decently well-known (it's already popular or the lead has been referred by someone else) or the CTA   follows a flow where a lead's been fed a series of strong value props.

"Learn More" is ideal in situations where a lead only has very limited knowledge of a product, ie., in the case of a banner ad where you only have 20 or fewer words to encourage a lead's interest or curiosity. In this case, "Learn More" feels less risky to a user who might not be ready to sign up, therefore increasing conversions/clicks.

Thoughts? Any research out there on this?

Comment: Welcome to UXSE. Not everyone is familiar with the term CTA or they may mistake it for another abbreviation. You should define the abbreviation at least once in your original question.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to UXSE!

From a quick Google search on CTAs [I found this article](https://adespresso.com/blog/learn-vs-sign-vs-download-whats-best-call-action/) that analyzed ~37000 Facebook ads and also made their own A/B/C testing.

They compared "Learn More", "Sign Up" and "Download".

> The average click-through rate of call-to-actions was 0.906% for “Learn More,” 1.005% for “Sign Up” and 1.001% for “Download.”

These numbers are almost identical and shows that there is **no big difference in terms of click-through-rate.**

However,

### from a UX perspective you should always aim to use the copy that best describes the action/what the user will get next.

Answer (score 1):

"Learn More/Find Out More" as such are fine. But if you try to hind behind these actions signing it, this can be bad.

If you use "Learn More/Find Out More" for anything except really *immediately* providing more details, this can make an impressions that the web site is just trying to hide that user is signing in, that this is kind of trick to engage user to do something that he would otherwise not do. This will make your web site suspicious and you will loose the trust of potential users or clients.

Comment: Second this. Nothing frustrates me more than a "Learn more" that leads to sign-up page before the site will tell me more. I might not sign up _after_ I've learnt more, but with very few exceptions, I won't sign-up _before_ I've learnt more, so would just go elsewhere.

Comment: There is also the problem that users who *already* have the intention to sign up won't know how to do that when the signup screen is mislabeled as "Learn more".

Answer (score 1):

The two CTAs indicate two different actions, or at least is what a user could expect: a "signup" means a great engagement from the user (leave your personal data, input and remember your password, ect.) while a "learn more" means just read some details more and then decide. One of the principle of the good UX is to be not misleading: the copy should clearly indicate what's next. If you are just trying to catch as many clicks as possible, this could transform in a very bad UX and very bad customer experience as well.

I agree with you that the more the user knows about your product, the more he's likely to signup. According to the AIDA funnel concept, your users must pass the Interest phase before the Decision phase, and finally go to the Action phase. I would say a "learn more" is a CTA for the Interest phase, while a "signup" is a CTA for the Decision phase. You are trying to capture two different users (or better: users in two different mental phases).

Long story short: use both CTA for ensuring to capture both clients. You did not specify the context of this CTA, but you can use a pop-up or a box for the learn more option, to not interrupt the main navigation.

Answer (score 0):

"Get Started" or "Continue" impose sense of compliting a task. People will feel strange if they dont click those because our nature pushes us to complete things.

Check out [Ultimate Guide How to Optimize Registration Form for Higher Conversion](https://selleo.com/blog/how-to-optimize-registration-form-conversion-rate) for more ideas